# php maintain date increments in months, weeks, days from past date to present date

Tags: php, date, math, time, increment

I'm struggling to formulate this question correctly.

I have a php time() entry in a mysql table column called renew. I have a second entry in the same row under the column type which decides when to update the row, namely: daily or weekly or monthly from the renew column value (date).

How this script works:
In this example on row id 1; the balance must be updated to reflect the budget monthly. The renew date must also be updated to reflect the next monthly incremented date after the update has taken place.

in row id 2; This will take place weekly. and so on.

for example:

```
   | id |    renew   |   type   | budget    | balance  |
   |----| ---------- | ---------| ------    | -------  |
   | 1  | 1611214417 | monthly  | 10,000.00 | 3,000.00 |
   | 2  | 1643614417 | weekly   | 4,000.00  | 600,00   |
   
   id 1 = 2021-01-21 07:33:37;
   id 2 = 2022-01-31 07:33:37;
```

in row id 1 how to get the next update date from today?

```
  //the time entry 
   $now = time():
   $today = 28/02/2022
   $updatetime = $table['renew']; 
   $updatetype = $table['type'];
```

How i did the weekly:
from the $updatetime variable above, I incremented the variable with one week until it just passes the $now time.

```
// what I've done for weekly and seems to be working
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000000; $i++ ){ //random high number for incrementing
 if($updatetime < $now){
       $updatetime = $updatetime + (86400 * 7); //add one week
 } else {
 return;
 }
 }
 // the next update will now be the new $updatetime for weekly
```

How can i do this for the monthly? there are no fixed days in a month, the renew date could fall on the 31 of the month or 29 of February and then the current month could only have 30 days or 28 days.
This is where my issue lies.

If you can assist me.

Comment: Add `show create table` & couple row entries for the question.

Comment: Sparkot i updated my question with a table, it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use PHP [DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that is much simpler to manipulate the date time using [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```
<?php

$today = new DateTime();

$updatetime = '19/01/2021'; // $table['renew']; //19/01/2021
$updatetype = 'weekly'; //$table['type']; //daily || weekly || monthly
  
$updatetime = (new DateTime())->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', updatetime);

// what I've done for weekly and seems to be working
 if($updatetime < $today){
    // $updatetime = $today; // reset to today if needed
    $updatetime->modify('next week'); // add one week
 } else {
    return;
 }
 
echo 'Next time of weekly update '. $updatetime->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// Output: Next time of weekly update 2022-03-07
// without time reset: Next time of weekly update 2021-01-25
```

Other examples of date manipulation using relative formats:

```
<?php
$today = '2022-02-28';

$t = new DateTime($today);

// print the source date time
echo $t->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;

// examples of continuously manipulate the date time origin
echo $t->modify('next week')->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
echo $t->modify('next month')->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
echo $t->modify('next year')->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
echo $t->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
/*
Output:
2022-02-28
2022-03-07
2022-04-07
2023-04-07
2023-04-09
*/
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/Aip6VM)  [Live demo without time reset](https://ideone.com/j74eqV)

**TIP**:
Convert your `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly` into infinitive `day`, `week`, `month` so you will be able to use its value directly  using `$table['type']` into the date time manipulation:

```
<?php
$updatetype = 'week'; //$table['type']; //day || week || month
$updatetime->modify('next ' . $table['type']); // add one xxx dynamically!
```

**TIP2***
Use ISO date format `Y-m-d` to simplify your codding.

```
$updatetime = '2021-01-19'; //'19/01/2021'
$updatetime = new DateTime($updatetime); // That's it!
```

Comment: Hi,This answer is interesting, but it makes the next row update one week from today

Comment: So the 'next week' should be based on `19/01/2021` , ie. `2021-01-25`? Confirm  and I will update my answer.

Comment: yes the next update will be from 19/01/2021 but the new date must be in exact increments from 19/01/2021 the new could be 1 or 2 or 3 ... days from today.. Im not sure how to work it out.. the new date will be based from the original renew date 19/01/2021

Comment: also for monthly updates

Comment: I have removed the `// $updatetime = $today; // reset to today if needed` .  For `next month` is the solution same. you can use it dynamically, see the first tip.

Comment: very interesting: does the $updatetime->modify('next week'); stick to the increments of the original date? and then also for months do i just make $updatetime->modify('next month'); ? im going to test it quickly, will revert as soon as..

Comment: Yes, `$updatetime->modify('next week');` it manipulates the `$updatetime`. See the demo! If needed you can create copy of the original variable and modify its copy. 
Or even you can simply create a row of incremental dates using `while` but it is different story.

Comment: Hi Ino, The script shows the next update as 2021-01-25 which is one week after the original update day, but it must reflect the next update day from today. So it could be for example 2022-03-02 if it makes more sense..

Comment: I can still use this though to create a loop until the date exceeds today.. This will help me, thank you Ino

Comment: I am lost now.  Original date `2021-01-19` plus one week is `2021-01-25` without date time reset OR next week from today  `2022-02-28` is `2022-03-07` with the reset.  Where do you get the date of `2022-03-02` ?

Comment: it was just a example date..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ino's answers i worked it out like this:

```
 $today = time(); // can use DateTime() too.
 $updatetime = '1611214417'; // $table['renew']; //19/01/2021
 $updatetype = 'weekly'; //$table['type']; //daily || weekly || monthly
 
 echo $updatetime.'<br>';

  for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
  if($updatetime < $today){
  $updatetime = strtotime("+1 week", $updatetime); // can add week month day
  } else {
  break;
  }
  }

  echo $updatetime.'<br>'; // just for comparison

  echo date('Y-m-d', $updatetime); // 2022-03-03 works out perfectly
```